# jquery mobile reflow table refresh issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi everbody i am trying to use the jquery mobile reflow mode and try to update the contents dynamically using refresh code provided in the jquery mobile demos [link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/tables/reflow-refresh.html) . when i try to update it is appending data to previous values (especially in mobile screen only) not in desktop i am posting image of that one also below. have any body experience this kind of behavior or it is a bug [image]

Comment: show us your code pls..

Comment: i am just using the code from jquery demos .  if you want to see i will post it

Comment: just saw the code.. i think this is default behaviour of table when the screen size is small..try resizing your browser window ..ul know then ..

Comment: ya i have seen after resizing the window it is becoming normal but before it is adding duplicate labels and in mobile i dont think we can resize the browser so it will create some confusion .so, still i dont know whether it is normal behavior or not

Answer (score 1):

You must refresh your table and use .trigger('create') to avoid the duplicated label

try to use this :

```
var row = "<tr><td></td></tr>"
$("#YourTable").append(row);
$("#YourTable").trigger("create");
$("#YourTable").table("refresh");
```

if you have a loop try to use :

```
for()
{
    var row = "<tr><td></td></tr>"
    $("#YourTable").append(row);
}
$("#YourTable").trigger("create");
$("#YourTable").table("refresh");
```